# How can I open SPSS data file that appeared the dialogue as the specified file is empty "

Tags: windows-10, statistics

I can't open my SPSS data file due to the error which show "the specified file is empty".

It happened after window was shut down suddenly from electricity probably. But I still can see this file in the folder showing file size. How can I open this file. I am urgent need of help Please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for that I am panic.

Comment: I am doing data entry to SPSS. While working on SPSS file, electricity is out and my computer was shut down. When I reopened the SPSS file that I am working on, I cannot open the file. The dialogue appeared as " The Specified File is empty. Select another text file". However I can see the file in it's folder by still showing its file size.